# ASP.Net simple login page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a simple log in page in ASP.net and this is my code:

```
protected void Submit1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  // Validate the user against the Membership framework user store 
  if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text)) 
  { 
    // Log the user into the site 
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, Persist.Checked); 
    Response.Redirect("test-records.aspx"); 
  } 

  // If we reach here, the user's credentials were invalid 
  Msg.Visible = true; 
}
```

I don't know whats wrong because it shows no error and it just refreshes with no error
even the label msg is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using a MembershipProvider, and since it seems that there is nothing special have been done in your code, why not use the Login Control, and give it the membership provider class, and thats it!.